# SQL Query (pl/sql) for a complicated logic

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-server, oracle, plsql

I have been stuck with this problem for a while. First I will explain the table structure

There are four tables in my system

**Domain**

> ```
> Columns: 
>       DomainID (primary key)
>       DomainName
>
>  Data:
>         DomainID  DomainName
>       1000        Google.com
>       2000        mySql.com
> ```

**WebPage**

> ```
>  Columns:
>       WebpageID   (primary key)
>       WebpageName
>       DomainID   (FK from domain table)
>  Data:
>     5001   SearchPage.html   1000
>     5002   Welcome.html      1000
>     5003   ContactUs.htm     1000
>     5004   AboutUs.html      1000
> ```

**PluginType** (PluginsType that can be added to a web page)
                This table lists the plugin types available for each Domain

> ```
>   Columns: 
>          PluginType     (primary key)
>          DomainID       (primary key)
>          PluginTypeName  
>
>    Data
>         PluginTypeID        DomainID        PluginTypeName
>          8000                 1000             searchButton
>          8001                 1000             DropDownMenu
>          8002                 1000             InteractiveForm
>          8003                 1000             loginForm
>          8004                 1000             LogoutForm
> ```

**Plugin:** Each webpage in a domain can use any number of plugins.

> ```
>       Columns:
>              PluginID     (primary key)
>              WebpageID    (FK from webpage table)
>              pluginTypeID (FK from plugintype table)
>
>       Data:
>          pluginID        WebpageID(Name)         PluginTypeID
>           10001             5001(SearchPage.html)   8000(SearchButton)
>           10002             5001(SearchPage.html)   8001(DropDownMenu)
>           10003             5002 (Welcome.html)     8000 (SearchButton)
>           10004             5002 (Welcome.html)     8001 (DropDownMenu)
>           10005             5002 (Welcome.html)     8004 (lotoutform)  
>           10006             5003 (ContactUs.htm)    8003 (loginForm)
>           10007             5004 (AboutUs.htm)      8002 (loginForm)
> ```

Now what I want is, given a domain ID, I want the list of all webpages-plugins available, in such a way that the plugin is not repeated in more than one webpage.
To put in another way, webpage-plugin combination for each plugin, in such a way that the plugin is not repeated in more than one web page.

So for the domain 1000(google.com)

The result I want is

> ```
>           5002 (Welcome.html)     8000 (SearchButton)
>           5002 (Welcome.html)     8001 (DropDownMenu)
>           5002 (Welcome.html)     8004 (lotoutform)
>           5003 (ContactUs.htm)    8003 (loginForm)
> ```

I have chosen only 5002 and 5003 webpages, because they include all the plugins for the domain 1000(google.com). 
There is one more thing, it is preferred to select a webpage with just one plugin. But I am interested in finding out the solution without this preference, later maybe I can improve on the solution.

Comment: Are you looking for the "DISTINCT" command?

Comment: For what database specifically?  Syntax is not 100% the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at it from the other perspective, since you are returning one row per plugin-type, you need all the plugin-typess on a domain, along with a sample page where that plugin-type is, well, pluged-in, something along the lines of:

```
Select PluginTypeName, 
  (select top 1 WebpageName 
    from WebPage w
      inner join Plugin p on p.WebpageID = w.WebpageID
    where p.pluginTypeID = pt.pluginTypeID) as SampleWebPage
From PluginTypes pt
```

this will return something like:

```
searchButton    SearchPage.html
DropDownMenu    SearchPage.html
InteractiveForm null
loginForm       ContactUs.html
lotoutform      Welcome.html
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  PluginTypeId,
        (
        SELECT  webpageID
        FROM    plugin pi
        WHERE   pi.pluginTypeId = pd.pluginTypeId
                AND webPageID IN
                (
                SELECT  WebPageID
                FROM    WebPage
                WHERE   DomainId = 1000
                )
        ORDER BY
                (
                SELECT  COUNT(*)
                FROM    plugin pc
                WHERE   pc.webpageId = pi.webpageId
                )
        LIMIT 1
        ) AS WebPageId
FROM    Plugin pd
WHERE   WebPageId IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Above result (submitted by SWeko) should work, I was trying it out, may give repeated results. Also, it groups results per domain... Here is a modification:

```
Select DISTINCT DomainID, pt.PluginTypeName, 
  (select top 1 WebpageName 
    from WebPage w
      inner join Plugin p on p.WebpageID = w.WebpageID
    where p.pluginTypeID = pt.pluginTypeID) as SampleWebPage
From PluginTypes pt
GROUP BY DomainID, pt.PluginTypeName
```